# Two headers in Drupal setup

Tags: 7

I am using drupal7 and some basic modules like organic group, views, panel, filedepot etc.

I have two headers as shown in image below. I am not able to understand the problem

[image]

Comment: is that ajax loaded content?

Comment: @Serjas: Thanks for the reply. The block which you see in the left side is coming from Ajax

Comment: Check return statement in ajax its probably returning full page.